# Why do I get AudioConverterNew error when using prepareToRecord?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, avfoundation

When I use the code:

```
 @IBAction func recordAudio(sender: UIButton) {
    recordButton.enabled = false
    stopButton.hidden = false
    recordingInProgress.hidden = false

    //recording the user's voice
    let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String

    let recordingName = "my_audio.wav"
    let pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
    let filePath = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathArray)
    print(filePath)

    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)

    try! audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: filePath!, settings: [:])
    audioRecorder.delegate = self
    audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true

    audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    audioRecorder.record()
}
```

I get an error return that reads:

```
2016-01-23 23:42:04.338 Pitch Perfect[3608:1266093] 23:42:04.338 ERROR:    1066: AudioConverterNew returned -50
```

It prints out 7 times.  All of these errors are being thrown by the last two lines (at least, it appears that way when I use random print statements to troubleshoot).  [Pitch Perfect is the name of my app].

Six of these error messages are being thrown by the following line:

```
 audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
```

One of these error messages is being thrown by the following line:

```
audioRecorder.record()
```

Does anyone know why this would occur?  I'm using a Mac running OS X 10.11.3.  I'm running Xcode 7.2.

One idea that has occurred to me is that, perhaps, my microphone is not functioning properly.  I can't find any place which discusses an error 1066 or AudioConverterNew return of -50 though, so I really have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own problem.  After continued error checking of my code, I determined this was not a code error, but rather, a system error.  I have an external monitor attached to my MacBook Pro.  A quick look in System Preferences -> Sound -> Input revealed that my Mac was set to use the microphone on the external display (it doesn't have one...).  I selected "Internal Microphone" as my INPUT device, then rebuilt my code in the simulator.  Viola! It worked!!